# Is a sequence of condition checks in WHERE clause predefined?

Tags: t-sql

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM [User]
WHERE [Value1] > 0
AND [Value2] / [Value1] > 3
```

I would want to avoid a division-by-zero situation. Can I be sure that the first condition be checked first and the second one will never get hit if the first one is false? I suppose the query planner is allowed to rearrange the sequence if it will yield more performance.

Comment: [Value1] / [Value1] > 3? I think you've mistyped, [Value1] / [Value1] will almost always be 1, unless of course you have 0 which in that case would be undefined.

Comment: Sure, mistyped, fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [User]
WHERE   CASE WHEN Value1 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE [Value2] / [Value1]  END > 3
```

, or even better:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [User]
WHERE   [Value2] / NULLIF([Value1], 0) > 3
```

Division by `NULL` is always safe.

Note than if you have lots of `[Value1] = 0` in your table and an index on `[Value1]`, then the following query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [User]
WHERE   [Value1] > 0
        AND [Value2] / NULLIF([Value1], 0) > 3
```

, will use the index and just skip the wrong values.

This, however, should not be relied upon and `NULLIF` should still be used. It's almost free, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for a conditional statement, an IF.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Generally no. The optimiser works out the best way to execute the query.

SQL does not produce explicit code: it's simply an instruction to the optimiser to return data in certain formats, orders, filtered etc.

```
SELECT *
FROM [User]
WHERE [Value1] > 0
AND [Value1] / [Value1] > 3

--could be this
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT *
    FROM [User]
    WHERE [Value1] > 0
) foo
WHERE [Value1] / [Value1] > 3

--but to be safe
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT TOP 2000000000 *
    FROM [User]
    WHERE [Value1] > 0
    ORDER BY Value1
) foo
WHERE [Value1] / [Value1] > 3
```

Comment: The optimiser may collapse it into one WHERE clause. The 3rd form arbritrarily tells the optimiser to sort before applying the outer WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

Your original SQL code will work perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters...

```
Value1 / Value1 == 1 //always...
```

but assuming its a different column.

```
SELECT top 20 * from [User]
WHERE
CASE WHEN Value2 > 0
    THEN convert(decimal(18,2), Value1) / convert(decimal(18,2), Value2) 
    ELSE 0
END > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not count on the server processing your conditions in the listed order.  Generally the optimizer will run them in whichever order it thinks is *faster*.  Normally what you have listed should be safe, but I've seen edge cases where the optimizer gets confused.

One good way to make the optimizer thing the `[Value1] > 0` condition will be faster is to have an index on `Value1` but *not* on `Value2`.